# Drywall finish for projector arm

Tags: drywall, mounting, projector

I'm working on a projector theater project. I have the drywall up and have a projector mount drilled into the stud/joist. Problem I'm running into is "how can I finish the hole in the drywall where the mount comes down?" I'm looking for something similar to a cable pass through but larger so that the project arm can get through.

Or, do you have any ideas on how to finish the drywall where the arm comes out?

Comment: Any reason you can't simply flat-tape to the pipe? Two-piece grommets may be available, but they're not really intended to replace good finish work.

Comment: What is the diameter of the mount, and is it round, or otherwise?

Comment: Can you post pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing the drywall can be neat if done well. But if you're lazy or not confident in getting your plaster work to look good around the projector arm, consider using a cover plate of some sort. Ideas:

- [Floor and ceiling cover plates](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-Floor-and-Ceiling-Plate-C5369/205154402)
- Custom cut and drill a wooden plate
- [Maybe even try a ceiling medallion](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-10-in-Smooth-White-Finish-Ceiling-Medallion-7703700/202191019)

Comment: the ceiling medallion is a great idea. That might work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the gap in the wall between the projector arm and the drywall, you should install tear away L bead and then drywall mud over it. You can use a stapler to attach it to the drywall, or use a spray adhesive like 3M Super 77.

The side with holes in the image below go on the face on the wall and help the mud adhere to it. The solid side goes into the hole and would be placed flat against the projector arm. After you add a few coats of mud, you can "tear away" the piece that is removable and you should have a perfect finish!

[image: Tear Away]

Comment: Would this work to wrap a 2" pipe, for example?

Comment: This is a great idea but I'm looking for something out of box to avoid any instillation issues.

Comment: Isherwood, a 2" pipe would probably be too tight of a radius to use the tear away. Google "2 inch pipe escutcheon" for this situation. They come both in solid flange and separating flanges so you can install them before installing the pipe, or after the pipe is installed without cutting anything.